# The DownloadManager won't run on Huawei devices

Tags: android-download-manager, huawei-mobile-services

I was making the download process using downloadmanager libary, everything work, but when I ran it on other devices with various versions of Android, but when I tried to run it on a Huawei device the download didn't want to run, I was confused and had searched Google but didn't get the right search results . these are my download manager code.

```
        DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload));
        DownloadManager manager= (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"app-release.apk");

        DownloadManagerId=manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Haven't used downloadmanager libary before, but what Huawei Devices are you using?

Comment: matepad T8 api 29

Comment: I am on a big project, where my customer orders several Android applications for his company and the device he uses is Huawei, but because there are some limitations with these devices, I advise my customers to use devices other than Huawei.